# How to get the size of union struct's void* value deserializes from flatbuffers

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I'm using flatbuffers to deserialize a data which contains a union struct like

```
struct ReqMsgUnion {
  ReqMsg type;
  void *value;
}
```

Schema:

```
 table Request {
        seq_no: uint = 0;                          
        msg: ReqMsg (required);
    }
```

Now I want to use memcopy() to copy 'value', but I can't get the correct size of 'value' because there are some '\0' inside (if I do not mistake).
I search on the Internet and find a method like "Add a dataLength in the schema", but I want to know whether there are other better ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean you can not get the correct size of what value points to.  And yes, void* discards all that info.

Comment: Your search already provided the answer!

Answer (score 3):

There's *no way* to extract from a `void*` the size of that which it points to (nor its *actual* type). That information (if needed) must be included explicitly in some other way.

Try never to use `void*` in the first place in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, it appears the `struct` is from C/C++ code, and the `table` is from a FlatBuffer schema. They are not the same language.

Now first, you cannot generally copy anything out of a FlatBuffer. Anything you get from the API, wether it is a union or a table pointer, points to a location in the underlying buffer, and its size is unknown. It may point to additional items in the buffer that are not adjacent in memory.

In the flatBuffers API, you get a `void *` because it may point to multiple unrelated table types. You should use the type you get to cast it to an actual table type. But like I said, even once you do it, you still can't copy it.